# How can I convert a array into an array of arrays using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I really need your help with this. I've been trying to convert it and look for documentation but I think I don't know exactly what I am looking for.

My Input file has this structure:

```
20010102,2301,0.95070,0.95070,0.95070,0.95070,4
20010102,2302,0.95060,0.95060,0.95050,0.95050,4
20010102,2303,0.95050,0.95070,0.95050,0.95060,4
20010102,2304,0.95060,0.95060,0.95060,0.95060,4
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
EU = np.loadtxt('data_s.csv', delimiter=',')
sample = EU[:5]
size = len(sample)
print (sample)
```

The output of that was this:

```
[[  2.00101020e+07   2.30100000e+03   9.50700000e-01   9.50700000e-01
    9.50700000e-01   9.50700000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30200000e+03   9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01
    9.50500000e-01   9.50500000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30300000e+03   9.50500000e-01   9.50700000e-01
    9.50500000e-01   9.50600000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30400000e+03   9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01
    9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30500000e+03   9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01
    9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01   4.00000000e+00]]
```

So I tried reshaping it (which I am sure isn't what I should have done):

```
sample = sample.reshape(size, 7)
print(sample)
```

and my output was exactly the same:

```
[[  2.00101020e+07   2.30100000e+03   9.50700000e-01   9.50700000e-01
    9.50700000e-01   9.50700000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30200000e+03   9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01
    9.50500000e-01   9.50500000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30300000e+03   9.50500000e-01   9.50700000e-01
    9.50500000e-01   9.50600000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30400000e+03   9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01
    9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01   4.00000000e+00]
 [  2.00101020e+07   2.30500000e+03   9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01
    9.50600000e-01   9.50600000e-01   4.00000000e+00]]
```

what I am looking for is an output of something like this:

```
[[[2.00101020e+07],  [2.30100000e+03],   [9.50700000e-01],   [9.50700000e-01],
       [9.50700000e-01],   [9.50700000e-01],  [4.00000000e+00]],
...]
```

I also tried this:

```
sample = EU[:5]
final = []
for line in sample:
    va = []
    for var in line:
        var = np.array(var)
        va.append(var)
    final.append(va)
print(final)
```

and the output was:

```
[[array(20010102.0), array(2301.0), array(0.9507), array(0.9507), array(0.9507), array(0.9507), array(4.0)], [array(20010102.0), array(2302.0), array(0.9506), array(0.9506), array(0.9505), array(0.9505), array(4.0)], [array(20010102.0), array(2303.0), array(0.9505), array(0.9507), array(0.9505), array(0.9506), array(4.0)], [array(20010102.0), array(2304.0), array(0.9506), array(0.9506), array(0.9506), array(0.9506), array(4.0)], [array(20010102.0), array(2305.0), array(0.9506), array(0.9506), array(0.9506), array(0.9506), array(4.0)]]
```

which happens to be a list, not an array. So i tried this:

```
final = np.array(final)
```

and that took me back to the starting point.

I am working on a machine learning project that should be able to take these inputs and at the moment they all look like each line is the input, nothing like each value is a separate variable.

Maybe I am thinking of this wrong. I tried using pandas but i realized that using numpy and going through the pain of having to figure this out is better than having pandas give me gigabytes of data that can pretty much be a few hundred MBs.

This might be silly but please help me out! I will be more than grateful for the help!

Comment: `sample[...,None]` or `sample[...,np.newaxis]` I am guessing.

Comment: `sample` is (5,7) shape, right?  Looks like you want (5,7,1) or maybe (35,1)

Comment: Yes actually right now I tried (5,7,1) and it worked well for me. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
sample = sample.reshape(size, 7, 1)
```

?

Comment: I haven't and I didn't know I could do that! The documentations of reshape don't exactly say much about how the reshaping is done! Thank you so much for the help! I just tried it and it worked!